# C/C++ NCURSES, get all characters typed in a WINDOW

Tags: c++, c, input, ncurses, handle

What I'm trying to achieve (more than “to reproduce”):

In other projects (not TUI contexts) I've used several GUI toolkit ([wxWidgets](https://wxwidgets.org/), [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/)), etc. (just to name a few)), and most of the time they have handy methods on widgets receiving user input (like “text control” (single and/or multi lines)), methods which are used to get the content of the widgets into any container/object (e.g. `string` (**1**)).

Is there any similar functionality in **ncurses**?

Lets say I have the following code:

```cpp
WINDOW *textarea = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);

/**
 * There, code for letting the user type text in the textarea 
**/

switch (ch)
{
    case KEY_F(4): // Save
        /**
         * What do I do from here
         * to get all the content of the textarea WINDOW
         * that the user typed in
        **/
        break;
}
```

Does ncurses provides such a feature?

I'm working on a lightweight terminal text editor (not a source code editor, simply a text editor), and it would greatly simplify my job if I could do such a thing with ncurses.

---

**Notes** (for the curious)

(1): For example the [`wxTextCtrl::GetValue`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html) which returns a [`wxString`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.8/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlgetvalue)

Comment: Ncurses is very low-level; it doesn't have widgets and it doesn't have do line editing (or textblock editing). But there is the [forms library](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form.3x.html), built on top of ncurses

Comment: @rici Thank you very much for your time and answer; you're right about this low level context when working with ncurses, and that's why I was searching for a way to avoid to handle all this tedious management of what I refer to as a `textarea` (similar to wxTextCtrl, or even `html textarea/text input` which make thing so easy). I'm gonna read the doc of the forms lib! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

curses doesn't have a notion of "containers".  It uses windows (whose semantics are defined by the calling application), and can get input characters associated with a window, e.g., using [`wgetch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) or [`wget_wch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html#h3-wget_wch).  The string-input functions call one of those.

However, the input streams for the wgetch/wget_wch functions are probably (unless you set up separate *screens*) the same input device.  It's up to the application to decide how to distinguish input from one or multiple windows.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas for your answer! I'm still reading the doc(1) about the functions to handle user input.

I'm still in confusion about the design of my ncurses miminal text editor project; at this point of my investigation I've came to the conclusion that I have to keep track of each and every char typed, and update my data for almost any user action (add/remove/insert char, add/remove line, etc). It seems very tedious and very error prone, and I wonder if I miss something...

Briefly, how would you go to design a minimal text editor?

(1) Mostly on invisible-island.net